# How to restore a KVM guest from USB backup

Tags: virtualization, backup-restoration

I took a backup of a guest OS running in an LVM.

When I took the backup I created a snpashot of LVM and mounted that
snapshot in some location.
Used rsync to copy its contents to a USB drive.
Can I boot "somehow"from this copy of Guest OS which is now  in USB drive?
I am using KVM on 64 bit 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new VM with all the same params, set it up with the same OS version and then restore using rsync the same way you backed it up

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be using Virt-Manager to create a new VM but point it to your disk instead. Although that might not work. I think Virt-Manager only uses LVM and flat files, no accessing usb file systems. Again this is all conjecture just try using that utility.

Comment: I have tried all those options are greyed out to make a clone of the machine.Any other suggestions